# ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection - cf push

Tags: node.js, nginx, deployment, cloud-foundry, cicd

I am trying to deploy react app to cloud foundary using manifest.yaml file. It throws the below error

```
ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection.
ERROR: Please check that you are running against the correct path.
ERROR: failed to detect: no buildpacks participating
```

Below is my configuration -

script in gitlab-ci.yaml

```
- cf login -u $CF_USERNAME -p $CF_PASSWORD -a $ENTRY_POINT -s dev -o $ORG
- cf push -f manifest.yml app-name --strategy rolling -b paketo-buildpacks/nginx
- cf logout
```

What is the right way to configure buildpacks for CF?

Comment: If detection is failing, it means the criteria for the buildpack you've set is not being met. For detection, this often means the file/folder structure of what you're sending with `cf push` doesn't match what is expected by the buildpack. For example, the nginx-buildpack requires an nginx.conf file, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack/#buildpack-user-documentation. Also, you're referencing `paketo-buildpacks` but using Cloud Foundry, which is likely to be a problem. You probably want the cloudfoundry/nginx-buildpack, but I don't know the details of your CF install.

Comment: @DanielMikusa Thank you, I had the problem with folder structure, which I have fixed now and the cf push goes through. But now my app crashes with the following line  -
`[API/0] OUT Process has crashed with type: "web" `  what could be the possible reason?

Comment: My suggestion would be to first look at `cf events` for you app and get the reason there. It may say "memory" or give you a Linux exit code you can look up. Besides that, look at the logs for your application. If you don't see anything, add logging statements to your app or increase the logging level.